# How do I handle a 403 error with Stripe Webhooks and Firebase Cloud Functions 2nd Gen?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments, webhooks

Im new in using Firebase Cloud Functions 2nd Gen
I had created a Payment link in Stripe and I want when user buy the item and completed,
the Stipe Webhooks will send info to my cloud functions so that I can update the info to Firestore

I had follow the instruction in cloud functions, but cant figure out what is the problem
npm install stripe done

I try buy an item from the payment link in stripe

the error from stripe webhooks is 403 ERR
title : 403 Forbidden
error : Your client does not have permission to get URL `/` from this server.

(My Step)
In Stripe

1. create a payment links https://buy.stripe.com/test_cN29BGcLx4aH2uk7ss
2. Stipe Webhooks add endpoint
   https://stripewebhook-kfxoivwllq-uc.a.run.app
   above is endpoint url I put
   url come from : exports.stripeWebhook = onRequest((req, res)=>{})
3. Configure environment
   firebase functions:secrets:set SECRET_NAME

Below is my code in functions/index.js file

```
const {logger} = require("firebase-functions");
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");


initializeApp();

exports.stripeWebhook = onRequest({secrets: ["SECRET_NAME"]}, async (req, res) => {
  const sig = req.headers["stripe-signature"];
  const endpointSecret = "whsec_XP7qiexIKzYwp8fHYFx0k9XXXXT";

  const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.SECRET_NAME);

  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.rawBody, sig, endpointSecret);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
    return;
  }

  // Handle the event
  switch (event.type) {
    case "checkout.session.async_payment_failed": {
      const checkoutSessionAsyncPaymentFailed = event.data.object;
      logger.log("payment_failed", checkoutSessionAsyncPaymentFailed);
      break;
    }
    case "checkout.session.completed": {
      const checkoutSessionCompleted = event.data.object;
      logger.log("completed", checkoutSessionCompleted);
      break;
    }
    // ... handle other event types
    default: {
      logger.log("Unhandled event type", event.type);
    }
  }

  // Return a 200 response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  res.send();
});
```

Error from Cloud Functions Logs :
textPayload: "The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated invocations or set the proper Authorization header. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: [https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#unauthorized-client"](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#unauthorized-client%22)

Error from Stripe Webhooks Response
the error from stripe webhooks is 403 ERR
title : 403 Forbidden
error : Your client does not have permission to get URL `/` from this server.

last few year Im using 1st Gen with functions.config() to get environment everything work fine
now 2nd Gen I cant figure it out.
is that any problem in my code ?

I had created a Payment link in Stripe and I want when user buy the item and completed,
the Stipe Webhook will send info to my cloud functions so that I can update the info to Firestore

Comment: It sounds like maybe you haven't configured stripe to use the correct url for this endpoint code.  Please edit the question to show all of the steps you used to configure this so that we can reproduce it on our own.

Comment: When and where are you seeing the 403 error? Is this from your own request or logs in your Dashboard? How is the endpoint configured? Can you post a dummy event to the endpoint yourself?

Comment: Thanks for yours reply, I have edited with my step @DougStevenson

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and what worked for me was deleting the cloud function and redeploying it